# Deep linking is not automatically opening when app in background mode on Android 12 but was working fine in Android 11

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation, react-native-deep-linking

I am encountering an issue where deep linking is not automatically opening my React Native app in Android 12 devices. However, deep linking functionality was working perfectly fine in Android 11.

**Expected behavior:**
The app should open automatically when a deep link is triggered from app is in background, as it does in Android 11.

**Actual behavior:**
The app does not open automatically when a deep link is triggered from app is in background in Android 12. Also that deep link URL working fine in the web browser.

**Additional information:**

- I have verified that the intent filter for deep linking is correctly set up in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- The app has the necessary QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission requested in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- I am using the latest version of the react-native-navigation library (specify version number).
- Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) versions are up to date (provide version numbers).
- The issue is reproducible on multiple physical devices and emulators running Android 12.
- There are no error messages or warnings related to deep linking in the logs.

Comment: Are you trying universal deeplinks `(https://...)`? Or app scheme deeplinks?

Comment: I am using scheme deeplinks

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but since Android 12, you will need a digital assets file on your domain/web server.

Pre Android 12 are not affected.

Here are the two links you will need to read up on. Generate your digital assets file, upload to your webserver and verify it.

https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks